# Oscillation of a function at a point

Tags: real-analysis

Why do we need to take open neighbourhoods around the point in consideration while defining oscillation of a function at that point?
(We're working in R)
For ref. Bartle & sherbert(introduction to Real analysis) p. 348 C.2
              Goldberg(methods of real analysis) p. 157 7.2A
Edit: my query is while reasoning for it I don't see how it would affect if we don't necessarily take open nbhd.s to arrive at a contradiction

Comment: Is this what you mean?  Define $O(f,E)=\sup\{ |f(x)-f(y)|:x,y\in E\} $ and then decide to use either  $$\omega_f(x_0)= \lim_{\epsilon\to0+} O(f,[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon])  \ \ \ or  \ \ \  \omega_f(x_0)= \lim_{\epsilon\to0+} O(f,(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon))   $$  for a definition of oscillation?

Comment: Yes. Precisely put, this is what I mean.

Comment: They are equivalent.  Use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to prove that a function is continuous in that point iff the oscilation is zero.
Also you can aproach as much as you want to the discontinuity, and measure the skip.

Comment: My problem is that I don't see how it would affect us if we don't necessarily take open neighbourhoods

Comment: we take open neighbourhoods because is the way you can aproach to a point as much as you want. So if you want to prove that $f $is discontinuous in a point $x$ (it has a skip in the graph for example) you will need to find a close point to x, $|x-x_o|<\delta$ an open neighbourhood,  then $m<|f(x)-f(x_o)|<M$, another open neighbourhood.